# Create a copy of string

Tags: python, string, copy

I have a class variable `my_set` which is a set, and into which I am adding strings:

`MyClass.my_set.add(self.some_string_property)`

My problem is that the instance of the class that runs the above may get garbage collected at any time, and when that happens I think I lose its `some_string_property` in `my_set` class variable.

In order to preserve `some_string_property` in `my_set` for each instance, I need to create a copy of it and store *that copy* into `my_set`. What is the right way to do so? I've tried the  `copy` module but it doesn't work on strings.

Comment: How do you know the instance gets garbage collected? What are the actual symptoms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you keep at least one reference to the string, it will not be garbage collected (and if you have no references left, then you have no way of accessing it anyway).